# How long does it take to remove a "duplicate" tag?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I asked a question. This was provided by me marked as a duplicate. And *no*, the error is not in "event.location (in: self)". I have made this clear with a processing. How long does it take for the mark to be removed, because I've been waiting for a long time?

*[Run an SKSpriteNode object along a line drawn with the mouse in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543584/run-a-skspritenode-object-along-a-line-with-drawn-with-the-mouse-in-swift)*

Comment: But you did accept the duplicate your self. Was that in error?

Comment: It doesn't look like your edit was significatn enough to put it in the re-open queue: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57543584/timeline. I gave your question another edit but I'm not familiar enough on the topic to feel confident about a re-open vote. I did ping the commenter/close voter

Comment: I have accidentally marked it as duplicate. Actually I wanted to reject the request

Comment: Okay, that can happen. No harm done.

Comment: In general the process is that your question gets submitted to the re-open queue and is reviewed there. That normally takes 6 to 8 ...

Comment: Although I appreciate the humor @rene, I fear Jojo may not have a history of SO culture to get that you're kidding with that last one.

Comment: What do you mean by *"This was provided by me marked as a duplicate"?* Did you provide something else besides the question? Suggestions for having your own question closed? Something else? Do you mean (including the previous sentence) *"I asked a question, but it was marked as a duplicate."*? (Not rhetorical  questions.)

Comment: What do you mean by *"made this clear with a processing"* (seems incomprehensible)? (Not a rhetorical  question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally it takes a re-open vote or a significant edit on your part to submit a closed question into the reopen review queue. It is a bit unfortunate that you confirmed the proposed duplicate in error.

You could have @-replied the close voter as they left a comment under your question. Only in a [few cases close voters can be reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020). From the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57543584/timeline) you can learn what happened to a post. In this case it didn't show much after your edit.

I edited your question to make a bit more clear that your attempt in the proposed duplicate didn't work for you and after the original close voter responded to my ping I voted to re-open and send a [reopen-pls](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47410908#47410908) into the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where it was obviously was taken care of. If you only rely on the re-open queue it can take a few days for a post to be re-opened. The timeline will tell you that.

I consider the issue resolved for now.

Comment: Slight comment on "can't @-comment close voters" - according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020 if only one person was involved in closure (gold-badger or diamond mod) they can be pinged.